# Box with Arrow top and Border

Tags: javascript, html, css, border

I'm just going to create a box on the
edge has an arrow. I have quite often tried but unfortunately relevant solution.
I naturally inquired on the Internet and on the website, but unfortunately without success.
So it should look after:

[image]

the arrow should have the same border like the box and the same backgroundcolor

So it looks now

```
.arrow-up {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
}

#log2 {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px groove rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 54px;
    float: left;
    left: 29.965%;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 3.5px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dAdry/)**

I'm sorry for my english

Comment: http://cssarrowplease.com/

http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lotjh
these will help you to understand how css3 arrow works

Comment: For more cool effects in CSS, take a look at this link: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Your your height and width to zero and increase the borders to 10px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's updated fiddle: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2Gt7z/).
You can try with this CSS:

```
#log2 {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 15px auto 0;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
}

#log2:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ccc;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    top: -9px;
    right: 19px;
    background: inherit;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

However, this includes `transform` property which is a new feature and might not work in every browser.
Other solutions are fine but they won't let you add border to this little triangle. You pick the one that suits you.

**EDIT**:

Yet another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dAdry/22/.
I also figured out **how to do this without `transform`**. You put two triangles, one grey and one white a little bit smaller.

```
#log2 {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 15px auto 0;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
}
#log2::before, #log2::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    right: 19px;
}
#log2::before {
    border-color: #ccc transparent;
    top: -10px;
    right: 19px;
}
#log2::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff transparent;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    top: -9px;
}
```

Try it out and let me know if it suits you.

Comment: Nice solution to the border issue.

Answer (score 1):

Create your triangle using :before

http://jsfiddle.net/dAdry/9/

```
#log2:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 7.5px 8px 7.5px;
    border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    top: -8px;
}
```

Comment: i want that the arrow have a white background and the same border like the box

Comment: its the same like that what u write

Comment: I changed for white background. But I don't believe that is possible set a border.

Comment: look at my answer for a border

Answer (score 1):

```
.arrow-up {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        margin-top: 0px;
        border-left: 10px solid transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 10px solid gray;
        }
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vishalkin/dAdry/6/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/dAdry/27/

This creates a border. 
The CSS

```
               .arrow-up {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    margin:0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid gray;
    }
.arrow-inner {
width:0;
height:0;
     margin:1px 0 0 0px;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid white;   
}
     #log2 {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px groove rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
    position: relative;
    display: block ;
    margin-top: 54px;
    float: left;
    left: 29.965%;
    border-radius: 3.5px;
    }
```

And the HTML...

```
                    <ul id="log2" style="display: inline;">
                  <span class="arrow-up" style="top: -9px; left: 70.0%; position: absolute; background-size: 100%; z-index: 999;" ></span>
                    <span class="arrow-inner" style="top: -9px; left: 70.0%; position: absolute; background-size: 100%; z-index: 999;"></span>
                    <br/>How are u?<br/>Whats the matter? :D
                </ul>
```

Comment: i want that the arrow have a white background and the same border like the box